# The equation of continuity in isothermal system in spherical axis(transport phenomena)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, density

My homework is about finding the equation of continuity in isothermal systems in spherical axis, I can't imagine a workaround for that since its a little complicated for me to understand velocities and the differential surfaces that must be multiplied by the $\rho v\left(\mathbf x\right)$ where $\rho$ is density, $v$ the velocity and $\mathbf{x}$ is $r,\,\theta,\,\phi$.

I am not here asking for the full answer but I'd be happy if someone clear these things for me and enlighten me about how can I write the mass equilibrium on a spherical element.

Comment: Is it $\nabla\cdot\rho\mathbf v$ that you are confused about, or something else?

Comment: I'm confused with the surfaces that must be multiplied by pv(x)...

Comment: So it's the integral form (i.e., $\oint \rho\mathbf v\cdot d\mathbf S$) that you're considering and not the differential form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continuity equation is
$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\rho  \mathbf{v}} = 0 $,

Now you can substitute directly for $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\rho  \mathbf{v}}$ with the expression for divergence in spherical co-ordinates

$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = {1 \over r^2}{\partial \left( r^2 A_r \right) \over \partial r}
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial \over \partial \theta} \left(  A_\theta\sin\theta \right)
+ {1 \over r\sin\theta}{\partial A_\varphi \over \partial \varphi}$

The direct derivation using an element in spherical coordinates is slightly more difficult. It is fully worked out here : http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.in/2010/02/9-derivation-of-continuity-equation-in.html